# ROS Android project-rosmake failed

Tags: ros, rosdep-install, rosjava, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi guys, I am trying to set up the environment for developing a ROS Android application and I followed the tutorial [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/ApplicationsPlatform/Clients/Android) and I got stuck when I tried to rosmake "android_app_chooser". At first I get the error "Failed to find stack for package actionlib_java", but then by following  the tutorial to downgrade the rosjava_android repository seems to have solve the error.

So I run the rosmake command again, but this time I get another error "Failed to find rosdep daemontools for package android_app_chooser on OS:ubuntu version:lucid
[ rosmake ] rosdep install failed: Rosdep install failed ". Can anyone tell me where I did wrong and help me solve the problem?

Edit1:By the way, by browsing through other questions here I found some proposed solution such as running `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-turtlebot` but to no success as when I tried to run `sudo-apt-get install daemontools` it says my daemontools is already the latest version.

P/S: Honestly I have tried few approaches on setting up such environment but to no success so far. I would really appreciate if someone can upload a VM image that can run the android examples as well as developing one. Thanks a lot.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44209/ros-android-project-rosmake-failed/) by [steven7](https://answers.ros.org/users/3213/steven7/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-09-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The current way to do Android / ROS development is to use the [android_core](http://ros.org/wiki/android_core) package by Damon Kohler. I don't think the ROS electric Android stuff is supported any more.

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2012-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [orion](https://answers.ros.org/users/2818/orion/) on 2012-09-21**:
I have followed the android_core package by Damon Kohler and it works well.  This is the correct and current way to do ROS on Android.